# Prism and Uno Platform in Wpf .Net.5 App. What Nuget Packages to use?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, .net-5, uno-platform

Given is an Prism Unity WPF .Net5.0 Application.

What are the right Nuget Packages to make Uno Platform to work along with Prism?

Prism offer:

- Prism.Unity.Uno
- Prism.Uno

Uno offer:

- Uno.Prism.Uno
- Uno.Prism.Unity.Uno

What is the right choice? When I can use both. What are the pro and cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the Nuget packages [`Uno.Prism.Uno`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Prism.Uno/) an [`Uno.Prism.Unity.Uno`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.Prism.Unity.Uno/8.0.0.13502-ci), you can see:

> This package has been **deprecated** as it is **legacy** and is **no longer maintained**.
>
> This package is now being **superseded** by the official Prism.Uno package
>
> This package is now being **superseded** by the official Prism.Unity.Uno package

Consequently, you should use the suggested alternatives `Prism.Uno` and `Prism.Unity.Uno`.